# cannot return reference to temporary value

Tags: rust

I am trying to learn Rust, and while doing so I wanted to try converting a struct object to a byte array, but I am running into issues doing so.

So I have this:

```
struct Node<'a> {
    id: u8,
    name: &'a str,
    data: &'a str,
}
impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    fn new() -> Node<'a> {
        return Node {
            id: 1,
            name: "superName",
            data: "some random desc2",
        };
    }

    fn to_buffer(&mut self) -> &'a [u8] {
        let mut size = mem::size_of::<Node>();
        size = size + self.name.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        size = size + self.data.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        println!("size {}", size);
        return &[self.id];
    }
}
```

but I am just getting the error "cannot return reference to temporary value"
And I am not 100% sure that I understand the error message to begin with... is it because `self.id` is only scoped to this function and would be removed from the stack when it is returned?

And is there any way around this?

Comment: `[self.id]` creates an array on the stack, `&[self.id]` refers to this array, but since this array was created inside a function block, it's dropped right when you exit `to_buffer` function block. Compiler complains that you try to return a reference on the dropped array

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Anything starting with `&` in Rust is a reference to a value, rather than a value itself. A `&[u8]` is a reference to a value which needs to exist elsewhere.

Because you create the value it's a reference to *within* the function, when the function returns, the value the reference points to no longer exists. (`id` still exists, but the slice containing `id` does not).

Instead, you can return an *owned* value, rather than a reference to one:

```rust
   fn to_buffer(&mut self) -> Vec<u8> {
        let mut size = mem::size_of::<Node>();
        size = size + self.name.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        size = size + self.data.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        println!("size {}", size);
        return vec![self.id];
    }
```

which the caller can then take a reference of if that's what they need.

Answer (score 6):

Since you originally wanted a reference to `self.id` but
considered as a slice of only one element, I would suggest that
instead of creating a new owned value (a vector, with heap allocation...)
you just use
[`std::slice::from_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_ref.html).

```rust
    fn to_buffer(&mut self) -> &[u8] {
        let mut size = mem::size_of::<Node>();
        size = size + self.name.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        size = size + self.data.len() * mem::size_of::<char>();
        println!("size {}", size);
        // return &[self.id];
        std::slice::from_ref(&self.id)
    }
```